# Appending multiple row results in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, database-cursor

I have a issue whether I'm facing an issue in concatenating multiple values using Cursor/ Function in postgreSQL.

I have a table names Products which contains several values of customers who buy different products,so there can be multiple entries for customers.

So my requirement is to get a part of an HTML if I give the customer email as parameter.

For example:
If I give ss@gmail.com which contains two entries in the table the output should be like shown below,

```
<p style="line-height: 14px; text- 
   align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;"> product 1 </p>
<p style="line-height: 14px; text- 
    align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;"> product 2 </p>
```

But now I'm getting  the details of one product only,like this,
      product 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
Append_Products(Customer_Email TEXT)
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
rowcount  BIGINT;
Products TEXT DEFAULT '';
HTMLscript TEXT DEFAULT '<p style="line-height: 14px; text- 
align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;">';
rec_Product   RECORD;
cur_AppendProducts CURSOR(Customer_Email TEXT) 
FOR SELECT "Name", "Product","itemcount"
FROM dl."Products"
WHERE "email" = Customer_Email;
 BEGIN
 -- Open the cursor
  OPEN cur_Appendproducts(Customer_Email);
 LOOP
  -- fetch row into the film
  FETCH cur_Appendproducts INTO rec_Product;
 -- exit when no more row to fetch
  EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND; 
 -- build the output
  IF rec_Product.itemcount > 0 THEN 
     Products := HTMLscript || rec_Product."Product" || '</p>';
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
-- Close the cursor
CLOSE cur_Appendproducts;
RETURN Products;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Is there some stipulation forcing you to use a cursor? This looks like it can be done with a `FOR` loop. It looks like you really want to `RETURN SETOF text` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think another solution you can try without the use of `CURSOR` could be like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION append_products(cust_email TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF TEXT
AS $$
DECLARE
    html_script TEXT DEFAULT '<p style="line-height: 14px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;"> ';
    rec_product RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec_product IN
        SELECT "Name", "Product", "itemcount"
        FROM dl."Products"
        WHERE "email" = cust_email
    LOOP
        IF rec_product.itemcount > 0 THEN
            RETURN NEXT html_script || rec_Product."Product" || ' <\p>';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

You can check out an example DBFiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qPA5TFjrwEwqnHhKeJoXea/1).

If you don't want a set returning function here is a single string return option:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION append_products(cust_email TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
DECLARE
    html_script TEXT DEFAULT '<p style="line-height: 14px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;"> ';
    rec_product RECORD;
    result TEXT DEFAULT '';
BEGIN
    FOR rec_product IN
        SELECT "Product"
        FROM "Products"
        WHERE "email" = cust_email
    LOOP
        result := result || html_script || rec_Product."Product" || ' <\p>';
    END LOOP;

    RETURN result;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

With a new fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qPA5TFjrwEwqnHhKeJoXea/2).

Comment: Hi Spratt, I tested the results,but the results are duplicating,I want the results to be appended into a single string.For the results ss@gmail.com there are two entries but the output resulted in 4 entries,I want it to be appended into a single row Do you have any suggestions about that?  But thank a lot of for your reply.

Comment: I don't see how it could be duplicating can you provide sample input data? I've updated the answer for a non-set returning function.

Comment: Hey Spratt,Thanks a lot!! This is exactly i was looking for :-) many thanks man.